# Why is a month to month fee listed on my 12-month apartment lease?

Tags: fees, rent, contracts, real-estate-leasing

I'm currently in the process of signing an apartment lease. As I was going through the terms, I noticed this:

[image]

In addition to my "Rent Due Monthly" there is a listed "Month to Month fee". Now, my confusion lies in the lack of clarity as to whether this is only applicable if I renew on a monthly basis at the end of my **12-month lease**. Is this typically the case?

Comment: Have you asked your landlord for clarification?

Comment: One possibility: you are "month-to-month" until the beginning of September, at which point the "real" 12-month lease kicks in for 9/1/2017 through 8/31/2018. (Yes, it sounds stupid, and I would be annoyed if this actually were the case.)

Comment: Is there any other place in the lease that mentions when you would pay the month-to-month fee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say where you are located, but in MN where I'm at, the boiler plate rental agreement that a lot of people use or use a modified version of, contains language that makes the lease turn into a month to month at the end of the specified term if it is not renewed or cancelled.
Look for such a passage in your agreement to see if it's the case, and there they might refer to this fee.